# Android. Вывод звука на наушники

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Я пишу приложение, которое используя TextToSpeech, выводит звук. При включении наушников в разъем, звук продолжает идти из штатных динамиков, игнорируя это включение. Собственно вопрос: надо ли как-то что-то менять программно, чтобы звук пошел в наушники или все должно произойти само собой? Ответа на свой вопрос я не нашел на просторах Интернета.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коллеги, по просьбе модератора публикую код который мне помог. Я не претендую на правильность, поскольку слабо разбираюсь в теме. Тем не менее:

```
    AudioManager am1 = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
    am1.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
    am1.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
    am1.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод isSpeakerphoneOn() позволяет определить, играет ли музыка через       динамики.

```
if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
// disable speakerphone button
}
```

Переключиться на динамики или отключить их можно через метод setSpeakerphoneOn():

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Подробнее:    http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/audiomanager.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я видел эту статью. В моей программе метод   `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);` или   `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` вообще ни на что не повлиял. audioManager получаю так:   `AudioManager audioManager= (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);`

Comment: ок, вы меняли моды для менеджера am.setMode? http://ru.androids.help/q8521

Comment: Спасибо за участие. Код, который позволил включить наушники и выключить динамики:   `AudioManager am1 = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am1.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        am1.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        am1.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` Только я не понял одного: во всех ли приложениях, которые я пишу сам, нужно использовать подобный код? Автоматически на уровне Andoid такого не происходит? Думаю, что это странно. И для гарнитур нужно добавить что-то такое?

Comment: @Сергей может быть, напишете ответ со своим кодом? А то он теряется в комментарии.